# Signals and Slots

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have written some code, where if I log in as a customer it should hide column `customer` (value of that column is 1). I need to pass parameter to the signals. I have used my `customerLogin` is `isSa`. How to pass these parameters to signals and slots?

`Main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   initialize();

   SafeOTPWindow w;
   Login login;
   login.connect(&login, SIGNAL(loggedIn()), &w, SLOT(show())  );
   login.connect(&login, SIGNAL(loginCancelled()  ), &w, SLOT(close()) );

   login.show();
   a.exec();
}
```

`Login.h`:

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Login;
}

class Login : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Login(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Login();
     bool isSa;

    signals:
    void loggedIn();
    void loginCancelled();

    private slots:
    void on_buttonBox_accepted();

    void on_buttonBox_rejected();

   private:
     Ui::Login *ui;
  }; 

 #endif // LOGIN_H
```

And here is my another file where I need to hide the column (`Customer`), `OtpWindow.cpp`:

```
  void SafeOTPWindow::initLogTable()
    {

     QList<OtpLog> logs;
     int ret = otpRepo.fetchOtpLogs(logs);
     if( ret != errorCodes::SUCCESS )
     {
         QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Critical, QString("SafeOTP"),
                       QString("OTPLogs could not be fetched"),QMessageBox::Ok, this);
         msgBox.exec();
         QLOG_ERROR() << "fetchLogs error " << ret;
         return;
     }

     QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(0,5,this); //5 columns
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Date")));
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Customer")));
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString("Server")));
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, new QStandardItem(QString("Authorized by")));
     model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, new QStandardItem(QString("Description")));


       for(QList<OtpLog>::Iterator lIt = logs.begin(); lIt != logs.end(); lIt++)
        {
           OtpLog& log = *lIt;
           QList<QStandardItem*> row;
           row.push_back(new QStandardItem(log.when.toString("dd MMM yyyy, hh:mm")));
           row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.customer)));
           row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.server)));
           row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.author)));
           row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.reason)));

             model->appendRow(row);
        }
     // set the data model
     ui->tblLog->setModel(model);
     //Set the column to hide
     ui->tblLog->setColumnHidden(1,true);


    // set the column widths
    int tw = ui->tblLog->width() - 5;
    int w = tw / 6;

      for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
      {
        ui->tblLog->setColumnWidth(i,w);
        tw -= w;
      }
     ui->tblLog->setColumnWidth(4,tw);
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the Qt documentation on signals and slots?  They have a simple `Counter` class which emits a signal when its value changes - and the signal has the new value.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: I tried it out But i am confused how to use it in the above examples

Comment: I recommend removing your second example, and sticking to just one problem. Once you have a solution for it, you should be able to work out the second problem yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the slot/signal example, you need to connect two objects having the same parameters. so let me modify a bit your example:

Let's say you have:

```
signals:
void loginStatusChanged(bool isLoggedIn);
```

In your Login method you will have something like:

```
bool status = checkLogin();
emit loginStatusChanged(status);
```

And then you should have a dedicated slot in SafeOTPWindow doing something like that:

```
void SafeOTPWindow::UpdateTableAfterLogin(bool isLoggedIn)
{
  ui->tblLog->setColumnHidden(1,isLoggedIn);
}
```

and you connect as usual:

```
connect(&login, SIGNAL(loginStatusChanged()), &w, SLOT(UpdateTableAfterLogin(bool))  );
```